# Examples of parametric equations for compact $n$-manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $m>n\ge3$?

Tags: soft-question, geometric-topology, big-list, computational-geometry, data-analysis

I've been messing with some computational topology texts and want to do some manifold/surface reconstruction on various data sets. I'd like to test on some purely geometric examples. Are there any explicit examples of compact $n$-manifold embeddings in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $m>n\ge3$, beyond spheres and tori? I've not found much with my search engine skills.

I'll admit I'm not terribly expert with theoretical geometry/topology; more of an applied mathematician, so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What do you mean by a parametric equation? Do you mean an explicit map from a domain in $R^n$ to $R^m$ whose image is your submanifold?

Comment: I suppose, yes. Think of the typical 2-torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $f(u, v) =( (a + b\cos(v))\cos(u), (a + b\cos(v))\sin(u),
c\sin(v))$. Like that, but $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, $3\le n < m$